# SQL Query To Join Two Tables On Closest Value

Tags: sql-server, join

">"I have the following data as shown below in the first two images.

```
dbo.Value1:     ID       Value       Date
                349383   -3268.32    7/14/2015
                573832   -1732.24    7/14/2015
                747583    49.85      7/14/2015
                958383    231.36     7/14/2015
                172737    1734.94    7/14/2015
                593983    25908.29   7/14/2015

dbo.ProductValue: ProductID  ProductValue   UploadDate
                  NULL       -6348          7/14/2015
                  958383      232           7/14/2015
                  172737      1735          7/14/2015
                  NULL        15392         7/14/2015
```

I want to fully join the two tables based on the Value and Product Value columns, so that the two tables join based on the closest values, as shown below. Does anybody know how I would be able to do this?

```
enter code here: ID      Value      Date        ProductID   ProductValue    UploadDate
                 349383 -3268.32    7/14/2015   NULL        -6348           7/14/2015
                 573832 -1732.24    7/14/2015   NULL         NULL           NULL
                 747583  49.85      7/14/2015   NULL         NULL           NULL
                 958383  231.36     7/14/2015   958383       232            7/14/2015
                 172737  1734.94    7/14/2015   172737       1735           7/14/2015
                 593983  25908.29   7/14/2015   NULL         15392          7/14/2015
```

Comment: I'm not really sure, based on your question, what makes the value "closest", and why two rows of Product Value still show nulls. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but this will match the rows from the second table id vs productid and if productid is null, then it will be matched for all rows, and the row that has the lowest difference between value vs. product value is the one where it will be assigned.

```
select *
from
  value v
  outer apply (
    select top 1 *, abs(p.productvalue - v.value) as diff
    from productvalue p
    where (p.productid = v.id or p.productid is null)
    and not exists (select 1 from value v2 where 
        (p.productid = v2.id or p.productid is null) and
        abs(p.productvalue - v.value) > abs(p.productvalue - v2.value))
    order by case when p.productid is null then 2 else 1 end,
      abs(p.productvalue - v.value) asc
  ) p
```

The outer apply with order by will select the best matching row, and the `not exists` clause inside it will only match it to the row that has closest product value.

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bbec/1)

Comment: Thank you for your help JamesZ. This helps me.