# SQL Server 2008 - Retrieve the nearest non null data

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have two tables: table 1 a package_id and a timestamp column for which I have no weight information available, table 2 a package_id, a timestamp and a weight column where I do have the information.

What I'm trying to do is fill in the table 1 weight information based on table 2 using the following restrictions:

1. use the closest package_id available ie. for package_id 1 use 2 if available, if not 3 etc
2. if there is only one weight available use it for all the missing package_id's
3. if two weights are available, use the higher one ie. for package_id 5, if 4 and 6 are available use 6

The code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TIMEGAPS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TIMEGAPS
CREATE TABLE #TIMEGAPS (PACK_ID INT, Local_Time DATETIME)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#REALVALUES') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #REALVALUES
CREATE TABLE #REALVALUES (PACK_ID INT, Local_Time DATETIME, WEIGHT INT)


INSERT INTO #TIMEGAPS VALUES
(1,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000'),
(1,'2018-01-20 18:50:00.000'),
(1,'2018-01-20 19:00:00.000'),
-----------------------------
(7,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000'),
(7,'2018-01-20 18:50:00.000'),
(7,'2018-01-20 19:00:00.000'),
------------------------------
(12,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000'),
(12,'2018-01-20 18:50:00.000'),
(12,'2018-01-20 19:00:00.000'),
(12,'2018-01-20 20:00:00.000')


INSERT INTO #REALVALUES VALUES
(2,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000',50),
(3,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000',70),
(4,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000',150),
(5,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000',60),
(6,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000',45),
(8,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000',55),
(9,'2018-01-20 18:40:00.000',25),
---------------------------------
(2,'2018-01-20 18:50:00.000',75),
(3,'2018-01-20 18:50:00.000',80),
(4,'2018-01-20 18:50:00.000',120),
(5,'2018-01-20 18:50:00.000',110),
(11,'2018-01-20 18:50:00.000',30),
---------------------------------
(8,'2018-01-20 19:00:00.000',70)
```

[image: Final result:]

EDIT:
I've adapted the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415068/sql-query-to-join-two-tables-on-closest-value) which I believe is what I need.

```
SELECT tg.PACK_ID, tg.Local_Time, p.WEIGHT
  FROM #TIMEGAPS tg
OUTER APPLY 
(
  SELECT TOP 1 *, ABS(tg.PACK_ID - rv.PACK_ID) AS diff
     FROM #REALVALUES rv
     WHERE (tg.Local_Time = rv.Local_time OR rv.Local_time is null)
     ORDER BY CASE WHEN rv.Local_time IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
     ABS(rv.PACK_ID- tg.PACK_ID) ASC
 ) p
```

EDIT 2:
 3. if two weights are available, use the highest PACK_ID ie. for package_id 5, if PACK_ID 4 and PACK_ID 6 are available use 6

Comment: So do you have any attempted sql that you can show us?

Comment: You have do define what "close" means. Are you looking for a "realvalue" with a "closest" package_id, if a lower and a higher pack_id is available, use the higher pack_id and then take the weight with the closest datetime?

Comment: @DeanOC I didn't have any suitable code to show at the time of the post.

Comment: @WolfgangK If I understand correctly, the way the table "realvalue" table is built if a pack_id is available at the specific datetime then it will have a weight associated to it.

Comment: @amphinomos Ok, so if I understand you correctly, you haven't understood your own question completely? You have secretly exchanged the screenshot, I swear that there was a weight of 5 yesterday. And still, I would like to have the screenshot explained. Is that the desired result? ANd why isn't 55 the weight of pack_id 7 at 18:40? Pack 6 and 8 are available and pack 8 has a higher weight. Please explain how to get to that 45.

Comment: @WolfgangK Did not mean for the screenshot to be changed secretly yesterday was a mistake. Apologies for that. For the weight of pack_id 7 you are correct it should be 55 (PACK_ID 8) but if I can't find a solution I will settle for the weight of PACK_ID 6.

Comment: @amphinomos So you changed the requirements to match a solution? All right. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

It uses a row_number by distance.

```
SELECT 
 PACK_ID, Local_Time, WEIGHT
FROM (
  SELECT g.PACK_ID, g.Local_Time, v.WEIGHT, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.PACK_ID, g.Local_Time 
                     ORDER BY ABS(v.PACK_ID - g.PACK_ID), v.PACK_ID DESC) AS RN
  FROM #TIMEGAPS AS g
  JOIN #REALVALUES AS v ON v.Local_Time = g.Local_Time
) AS q
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY PACK_ID, Local_Time
```

Comment: yes this works great, I was hoping to use Pack_id 8 instead of Pack_id 6 but this solution does the trick. I wasn't aware you could use ABS in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Well, after that ABS there's a second criteria in the order by. I based it on what I think you wanted. I.e. Descending v.PACK_ID.  But if you'd change part that to f.e. `v.WEIGHT ASC` you get a different result.

Comment: Actually then in this case I would use v.PACK_ID ASC as I don't want to use the WEIGHT as a criterion.

Comment: That seems different from what you said in that "EDIT 2: 3".  But anyway, just FYI, this query could be simplified even more. F.e. see [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51206403/4003419) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose we can start here. Make sure to initialize your tables before you run this. I assumed that #TIMEGAPS has a weight column based on your output.

```
DECLARE 
        @Pack_id INT
    ,   @Weight_id INT
    ,   @mloop INT = 0 

DECLARE @possible TABLE ( 
        id  INT IDENTITY (1,1) 
    ,   pack_id     INT 
    ,   weight ) 


BEGIN_LABEL:

SELECT  TOP 1 @pack_id  = PACK_ID 
FROM #TIMEGAPS AS g
WHERE g.WEIGHT IS NULL 
ORDER BY PACK_ID ASC 

IF @pack_id IS NULL 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Done'
        EXIT 
    END

INSERT INTO @possible (pack_id , weight ) 
SELECT PACK_ID , WEIGHT 
FROM #REALVALUES as r 
LEFT JOIN  #TIMEGAPS as g 
    ON g.WEIGHT = r.PACK_ID 
WHERE g.WEIGHT IS NULL 
ORDER BY ABS(@pack_id - PACK_ID) ASC , WEIGHT DESC

SELECT TOP 1 @Weight_id = weight 
FROM @possible 
ORDER BY id ASC 

IF (@Weight_id IS NULL)
    BEGIN 
            RAISERROR('No Weights available' , 18 , 1)
            EXIT 
    END

UPDATE #TIMEGAPS 
SET WEIGHT = @Weight_id  
WHERE PACK_ID = @Pack_id 

SET @mloop = @mloop + 1 

IF @mloop > 99 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Hit Safety'
        EXIT 
    END

SELECT @Pack_id = NULL , @Weight_id = NULL;

DELETE @possible;

GOTO BEGIN_LABEL 

SELECT g.PACK_ID , g.Local_Time , r.WEIGHT 
FROM #TIMEGAPS AS g
INNER JOIN #REALVALUES AS r
 r.PACK_ID = g.WEIGHT;
```

Im pretty sure RAISERROR() works in SQL 2008, but you can just replace them with print statements if they don't